# Fundamental proof of calculus and mean value theorem

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, limits-without-lhopital, formal-proofs

Hi I have been trying to learn the proof for the fundamental theorem of calculus and I found out that I need to learn the mean value theorem. However this theorem is quite strange as some proofs say that x needs to be differentiable only on the open interval $(a,b)$, and other proofs such as the one on khan academy state that x is differentiable on the closed interval. There seems to be lots of contradiction online, so is there a intuitive way to prove the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: For MVT, the function must be continuous on the closed interval and differentiable on the open interval.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of one of those contradictions that you mentioned?

Comment: I saw this video by khan academy titled proof of the fundamental theorem of calculus and he stated that for the mvt  of definite integrals c lies on the closed interval of a and b

Comment: If $c$ lies in the open interval $(a,b)$, then $c$ also lies in the closed interval $[a,b]$. What Khan Academy says is not false. It just isn't the stongest statement possible. But for their purpose in proving the FTC, they did not need the stronger statement. Just knowing that $c \in [a,b]$ was enough (I presume - I haven't seen their specific proof myself).

Comment: Is this due to the intermediate value theorem